# Is it possible to do a nested left join within another left join?

Tags: sql, teradata

So I want to do something like this:

```
SELECT ACC_NO
FROM
TABLENAME A
LEFT JOIN
(
    TABLENAME B
    LEFT JOIN TABLENAME C
    ON B.FIELDNAME = C.FIELDNAME
) D
ON A.FIELDNAME = D.FIELDNAME
```

How would I achieve this?

Comment: What DBMS are you using? This might work exactly as you wrote it.

Comment: Why the nesting?

Comment: Teradata SQL. Why shouldn't I nest? Is there a cleaner way to do this?

Comment: select from t1 left join t2 left join t3 etc

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, Try like below

```
SELECT A.ACC_NO,A.FIELDNAME
FROM
TABLENAME A
LEFT JOIN
(
    select B.* from TABLENAME B
    LEFT JOIN TABLENAME C
    ON B.FIELDNAME = C.FIELDNAME
) D
ON A.FIELDNAME = D.FIELDNAME
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you *can*:

```
SELECT ACC_NO
FROM TABLENAME A LEFT JOIN
     (TABLENAME B LEFT JOIN
      TABLENAME C
      ON B.FIELDNAME = C.FIELDNAME
     ) -- No alias is necessary
     ON A.FIELDNAME = B.FIELDNAME;
```

However, this is unnecessary and verbose.  Instead:

```
SELECT ACC_NO
FROM TABLENAME A LEFT JOIN
     TABLENAME B
     A.FIELDNAME = B.FIELDNAME LEFT JOIN
     TABLENAME C
     ON B.FIELDNAME = C.FIELDNAME;
```

I assume your query is actually more complex.  This version is presumably equivalent to:

```
SELECT A.ACC_NO
FROM TABLENAME A
```

Unless you are interested in actually seeing duplicates that might be generated by the `JOIN`s.